# Explain the file permissions, obtained from stat system call, using st_mode

Tags: command-line, permissions, stat

Code:

```c
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  struct stat st;
  if( argc < 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Require a path\n");
    return 2;   //return status error 
  }

  if( stat(argv[1], &st) < 0) {    //error, cannot stat file  
    perror(argv[0]);               //report erro with perror 
    return 2;                      //return status error 
  }

printf("The permissions of the given file are %o\n",st.st_mode);
return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
./statkk kk1.pdf
The permissions of the given file are 100664
```

Here **kk1.pdf** is a normal file.
I found that last three octal number indicates permissions for owner, group,and others respectively.

What do the first, second, third octal numbers indicate? 
[Please see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYxeV.png)

Answer (score 1):

Detailed explanation can be found at http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man7/inode.7.html

The mask `0100000` 
means that this is a regular file: `S_IFREG`